# Android: Sharing test code across modules

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-espresso, kotlin-coroutines

I'm having issues sharing code across different modules for testing my app.
I have a couple of classes (`TestCoroutineContextProvider` and `CoroutinesTestRule`) which I have placed in my `presentation` fragment.
In order to share the code between unit tests and UI tests, I have in my `presentation build.gradle` the following:

```
sourceSets {
        test {
            java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/testShared"
        }

        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/testShared"
        }
    }
```

This way I think I can have access to those two files in both my ViewModel and Fragment tests.
Nevertheless, although the files are imported correctly and there's no IDE error, when trying to run the tests I get the following:

`e: /features/account/src/test/java/me/myapp/account/AccountViewModelTest.kt: (35, 30): Unresolved reference: CoroutinesTestRule`

and the same thing for the other file.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue, no idea how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following to share the code across unit tests and instrumented tests:

1. In your app level `build.gradle` file, add the following:

```
sourceSets {

        // Share test utils between unit and instrumented tests
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/sharedTest/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/sharedTest/kotlin'
    }
```

where `sharedTest` is the directory / module name where the shared utilities will go in

2. Go to your module in which the `build.gradle` is located then navigate to `src` and create a directory named `sharedTest` and inside it create `kotlin`
3. Mark the `kotlin` directory as "Test Sources Root" by right clicking -> Mark As -> Test Sources Root so the IDE shows it as a test directory
4. Put your test utils in there
5. Do gradle sync
6. Enjoy!

Note: Even after this sometimes IDE shows errors / warnings when you try to use those shared utilities but if you run those tests, they will pass also when executing via gradle. Usually I have seen this problem to disappear after doing a gradle sync or re-launching Android Studio

Comment: can you share example as github repo